# Get avatar of the logged-in user in Wordpress

Tags: author, users, avatar

How can I get a user avatar to display in the header of my WordPress site? I've tried:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($post->post_author); ?>" title="<?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author ); ?>">
<?php if( get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $post->post_author ) != '' ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $post->post_author ); ?>" alt="" />
    <?php echo $curauth->display_name; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $post->post_author ), '80' ); ?>
<?php } ?>
</a>
```

but every time the logged-in user goes to a different authors post, the avatar changes to that authors avatar. I want it to be that when a user logs in, his/her avatar stays on the top of the page all the time. Can this be done?

Comment: get_avatar just places a default mistery man instead of a loged in user!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is pass the current users email address into the get_avatar() function.

```
<?php 

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
    echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 32 );
}

?>
```

Here are some links for specifics:

[get_avatar();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar)
[wp_get_current_user();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

A response to your new problem in the comments below:

```
<?php 

echo '<img src="'. get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $current_user->ID, 32 ) .'" />';

?>
```

I had one too many semicolons in that there code I gave you before, this ought to work.

*EDIT*

This will make it 10X easier for you. I dont know why I didnt do it this way to begin with. - I'll just add it into your example snippet the way you want it.

**The Real Answer:**

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($post->post_author); ?>" title="<?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author ); ?>">
<?php if( get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $post->post_author ) != '' ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $post->post_author ); ?>" alt="" />
    <?php echo $curauth->display_name; ?>
<?php } else { 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, $post->post_author ), '80' ); } ?>
</a>
```

Sorry about that.

Comment: is there any way to get the users image he uploaded? How to incorporate this function in YOur sollution also to have both options: <img src="' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $author->author_ID ) . '" alt="" />';

Comment: I tried adding  echo get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $current_user->ID, 32 ); and it outputs the link to the avatar instead of the custom avatar. I'm stuck. Could YOu please help me out?

Comment: Well, if it is outputting the link to the image, just put that on the inside of an img tag in your theme. <img src="<?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $current_user->ID, 32 ); ?>" />

Comment: I don't know where to put the code. It doesn't show anything. If I place it instead the original echo it gives me the error of: unexpected '<'

Comment: well You gave me the function but I'm placing the code in header.php , so this is not a valid way because I recieve an error. Oh well...

Comment: Thats because I messed it up, hard to put code into these dang comments. See the second comment block added to my answer.